# Question stuck in reopen queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing, reopen

[This reopen queue review](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/320453) has received 6 leave closed reviews, one from a mod, but the review is still active.

Comment: Reminds me of [How can a low quality post can get more than 15 or 20 reviewers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356261/295232) - but this is something different.

Comment: [status-review] - why did this Reopen review take 9 reviewers (including 2 mods) to clear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was one of the more complicated bugs I have ever encountered!

This issue was caused by our 'Leave Closed' modal being able to be submitted after selecting 'This question doesn't meet a [Community Specific] guideline' without additionally selected a community specific reason in the following modal when casting a vote that *should* close the review.

In this specific case this appears to have happened with the original moderator vote, which should have closed the review but did not because of the lack of a community specific reason. This meant that the subsequent votes from non-moderators were not recorded as terminal votes because preference was given to the existing moderator vote. That is why the review did not close until another moderator came and, in essence, overrode the original moderator vote.

While debugging this, I thoroughly searched for other examples of a review entering the same broken state because of a terminal vote being cast without a community specific reason and managed to find about 10 other instances where the same thing happened. I was unable to find a corresponding report for those instances, so thank you all for bringing this to our attention!

This issue should be resolved as of today, with multiple checks now in place to prevent a community specific vote being cast without a community specific reason. I have also updated the leave closed modal so that it clears your reason and your community specific reason upon exiting so that there is always a clean slate when you open the modal.

Comment: Fixing this [might have caused a related bug on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/3750257)

Comment: Potentially also related (MSE): [On some sites the "Leave Closed Reasons" dialog is missing the second page, for reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382389/335251)

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the 9th vote is the charm.

Either that or I've got super duper mod powers

[image: Timeline of post]

Comment: Really bizarre. I wonder if something was posted about this. I vaguely remember hearing something (or I'm imagining it).